# How to send last debounced request while request param is changing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was using React.useCallBack() to produced a debounced function, something like:

```
const debouncedFunction = React.useCallback(
    _.debounce(function, 2000),
    [someInputValue]
)
```

and trigger it using React.useEffect(), like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    debouncedFunction();
},[someInputValue])
```

When I change someInputValue(like typing "hi" in a Input component) in a short time(less than 2 seconds), 2 requests were sent, one with param "h" and one with param "hi".
I understand this was due to debouncedFunction was recreated every time someInputValue was changed, so multiple debounced requests cannot be merged into a single one. So what should I do to send one "merged" request with param "hi"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an extra lib:

```
const useDebounce = (value, delay, fn) => { //--> custom hook
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      fn();
    }, delay);
    return ()=> {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [value]);
};
```

SomeComponent.js

```
  const [someInputValue, setsomeInputValue] = useState(null);
  const fn = ()=> console.log(someInputValue);
  useDebounce(someInputValue, 2000, fn);
```

Comment: if there are 5 calls to the useDebounce with the same parameters within 2s except this time the fn accepting parameter with different values, how do u make sure the latest call (5th call) value will show after 2s?

Comment: Hi @DarrylRN, don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, can you give me more details?

Comment: nvm, I've found the answer to my question. Its about getting the last value of the debounce calls. Thanks!